# I am trying to filter the a dataframe based on the date column header like "data b/w 1 July to 5 July" but I am not able to retrieve the slice in py

Tags: python

DataFrame
[image]

```
att[[col for col in att.columns
     if col not in ('Region_x','City _x','Emp Id')
         and col >= datetime(2020,7,16) and col <= datetime(2020,7,20)]]
```

Above is the code I am using.

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Above is the error I am getting.

Comment: Your column names are strings. You can't compare them to datetime.
The easiest solution would be to make a list of equal length as the column names that contains the column names converted to datetime objects. You can use .strptime() for this. Then, you can filter the columns using this list.

Comment: Tried this----
from datetime import datetime
new=[]
for item in att.columns:
      try:
          new.append(datetime.strptime( item ,'%b-%y'))
      except:
          new.append( item )
          print("Doesn't work")
att.columns = new

But still getting the same error

Comment: That's the wrong time format. It does not match your column names. You should use the format "%d-%b-%Y" (case sensitive!) and then you should check whether the array `new` actually has datetime elements. Just print it to see whether it worked.

Comment: Thanks @MartinWettstein you really helped me get out of this!!